# Setting up a proxy server

Tags: php, proxy, lamp

So I have a server set up (LAMP) server, this proxy has access to the internal network and I need to give the outside world access to this proxy in order to perform tasks.

For example, you should be able to call that proxy with a POST request with the right parameters and the proxy should return the status of that post. Now let's say that post is being done in a php script called (something.php) in the main folder of that proxy. How do I give access to the outside world to access that proxy?

I hope this is clear, sorry I couldn't make it much clearer but if you have any further questions to clarify please let me know!

Comment: You're not being clear. You have a proxy that is facing both the internet and the internal network and you want people on the Internet to be able to access some server in your internal network that has PHP scripts via the proxy right? If that's the case, you should set up a reverse proxy.

Or is it the case that you want to build a proxy with PHP? I wouldn't advise you to...

Comment: That's exactly the case (sorry for not being clear :(). How do I set up the reverse proxy? (THANK YOU!)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To setup a reverse proxy with Apache, you have to use `mod_proxy` together with `mod_proxy_http`, since you want to proxy HTTP requests. The manual is [here](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_proxy.html).

A basic configuration straight from the manual is:

```
ProxyRequests Off

<Proxy *>
Order deny,allow
Allow from all
</Proxy>

ProxyPass /foo http://foo.example.com/bar
ProxyPassReverse /foo http://foo.example.com/bar
```

Now when the proxy server receives a request to `/foo/whatever`, it will itself download `http://foo.example.com/bar/whatever` and upload it back to the client.